# A Website like Connected Papers but for patents?

Tags: search, citationpatent

Is there a website that shows connections between citations and relevence between them like https://www.connectedpapers.com/ but for patents ?

Comment: That's an interesting site. I'm not aware of anything like that for patents, but Lens.org does allow reviewing patent citations and has some graphical displays. https://www.lens.org/lens/search/patent/structured